# Can't connect to Ubuntu VPS via SSH,SFTP

Tags: ssh, vps, ubuntu-14.04, fail2ban, csf

When I try to login to my VPS using SSH and SFTP it's not connect to the server. Then I power off and power on the VPS by the VPS provider control panel (digital ocean). Once it boot up, first few seconds I can access the server, after few minutes left I can't.

This is a Ubuntu 14.04.2+Nginx1.6.2 server. I use CSF,Fail2ban. What is the reason for this matter?

My /var/log/auth.log.

```
Apr 13 22:49:23 my-Server sshd[1569]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Apr 13 22:49:20 my-Server sshd[1071]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2200.
Apr 13 22:49:20 my-Server sshd[1071]: Server listening on :: port 2200.
Apr 13 22:49:22 my-Server su[1477]: Successful su for newrelic by root
Apr 13 22:49:22 my-Server su[1477]: + /dev/console root:newrelic
Apr 13 22:49:22 my-Server su[1477]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user newrelic by (uid=0)
Apr 13 22:49:22 my-Server su[1477]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user newrelic
Apr 13 22:49:23 my-Server sshd[1569]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Apr 13 22:49:26 my-Server sshd[1569]: Accepted password for root from 124.43.254.193 port 52514 ssh2
Apr 13 22:49:26 my-Server sshd[1569]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Comment: What does auth.log say after the failed login attempts?  Nothing? What about fail2ban.log?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe fail2ban is blocking you after a few minutes of failed login attempts.  Even if you're not sending those, someone else is. If the fail2ban rule is too broad, it could be locking you out.

If that's not it, then you should check to see if you're able to connect by telnet to port 22 on your host.